# Can I use 68% CI as an approximate of the standard error of Spearman's Rho and Variance

Tags: correlation, variance, standard-error, spearman-rho

I am currently trying to calculate the standard error of three different parameters.

1. Mean
2. Variance
3. Spearmans' rho

I have had difficulty in finding workable standard error formulas for the last two parameters. I have, however, found formulas for confidence intervals.

In the case of the mean, I know that the confidence interval and standard error are intimately related. A single standard error is equivalent to a 68% CI.

Therefore, my strategy for the other two parameters has been to also calculate 68% CI and refer to those as standard error. Is this correct, or is standard error not equivalent to the 68% CI in these cases?

Just for completeness sake, here is the R code I am using to calculate the SE for the last two parameters.

```
# Note that the objects Variances and SampleSizes are vectors of values, as I am calculating the "standard error" of multiple variances.

# Obtain the chisquare distribution values
UpperChis<-qchisq(rep(0.84,length(SampleSizes)),df=(SampleSizes-1))
LowerChis<-qchisq(rep(0.16,length(SampleSzies)),df=(SampleSizes-1))

# Multiply variance by the sample size divided by the chi square distribution value
UErrors<-(Variances*(SampleSizes-1))/UpperChis
LErrors<-(Variances*(SampleSizes-1))/LowerChis
```

I next use the CIrho function in the package mada to find the 68% interval for rho.

```
library(mada)
LowerCI<-CIrho(rho,SampleSize,0.68)[1,2]
UpperCI<-CIrho(rho,SampleSize,0.68)[1,3]
```

Comment: As a matter of terminology, a standard error is computed for a *statistic.* A statistic is calculated from data, whereas a parameter is a property of an assumed underlying distribution from which the data were sampled.